# Get PID from TID

Tags: ps, thread, pthreads

I run [`iotop`](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) to check on programs that are heavy disk users, in case I need to decrease their priority. Usually this is good enough, but `iotop` only shows thread ID (TID), and sometimes I want to know process ID (PID) so I can find out more about which process is responsible.

Unfortunately, while `ps` can display TID (a.k.a SPID, LWP), it doesn't have a flag to take a list of TIDs the way it does for a list of PIDs with `--pid`. The best I can do is list TIDs and then `grep` the output. For example, if the thread id is 792, I can do

```
$ ps -eLf | grep ' 792 '
```

which works reasonably well, but is a little inelegant.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can always do:

```
ps -eLo pid= -o tid= | awk '$2 == 792 {print $1}'
```

On Linux:

```
$ readlink -f /proc/*/task/792/../..
/proc/300
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
$ echo /proc/*/task/792(:h:h:t)
300
```

Comment: But what if there are 2770 tasks!

Comment: @IrfanLatif Could you elaborate?

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver I use `cgroups` on Android to control CPU/RAM usage, internet connectivity etc. Cgroups go for TIDs, not PIDs. Two TIDs belonging to same PID can be in different cgroups. So I have to deal with thousands of TIDs. Loops, pipes make it slow. So I was looking for some native code solution, not a programmer myself.